# How to migrate from imports using <script> to module bundler?

Tags: angularjs, npm, webpack, bower, bundling-and-minification

I have a project which uses Angular. It does not use a task manager nor dependency manager and all libs are stored in repo and included using plain old `<script>` tag like `<script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>`.

I want to modernize the application by introducing a module bundler and automating the build process. The original idea was gulp + bower, but I see that webpack + npm3 are a trend now.

There is no issue with gulp + bower because of things like `gulp-inject`, but I can’t find anything similar which works with webpack.

Are there any tools which would allow me to use the existing code as it is and write only new modules using webpack?

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to ask here.  "Please share your thoughts/experience" isn't a question, and the body of the question reads like you are trying to ask for a step by step guide, which isn't what this site is for.

Comment: @Claies i'm looking for a certain solution which would allow me to start using module bundler but keeping all legacy code in place with no critical changes. I believe that someone has already been doing this with any legacy system, that's why i asked for shared experience.

Comment: so what you need is  a module bundler like webpack-module-bundler to be used with gulp?

Comment: @pritishvaidya no. I need to make the bundler like webpack to work with legacy js files, which are currently included using <script> tag, so that i can write new UI components with ES6 imports, but leave all existing js files as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution i've got so far. Since the webpack requires a single entry point per bundle, i still have to import all those legacy js in a single file. So i decided to use ES6 `import` (or webpack's require) in that entrypoint called index.js

here's the how webpack config looks like

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var basePath = __dirname + "/target/app";
module.exports = {
    context: basePath,
    entry: {
        app: './index.js',
        vendor: './vendor.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: basePath + "/build",
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel?presets=es2015', exclude: /node_modules/},
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            "$": "jquery",
            "jQuery": "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            "_": "lodash"
        }),
    ],
};
```

and so in index.js i did following

```
import './app/component1.js'
import './app/component2.js'
//all the rest imports from index.html
```

as for the third part libraries like `jquery`, `angular`, etc... i decided to describe that imports in separate bundle and so there's another bundle called vendor.js

```
import './libs/lodash.js'
import './libs/jquery.js'
//and all the rest libraries
//note that here we can use now libs from npm node_modules like
import 'angular' //will take angular from node_modules/angular
```

Important thing which i faced while doing this, is that legacy modules are not really compatible with webpack because of using global variables like `$`, `_`, etc... `ProvidePlugin` helps here and add `require({module})` to the modules where the provided `{variable}` met as it's described in config `'variable': 'module'`

Note that i used `CommonsChunkPlugin` to avoid having dependent modules in both bundlers, like angular is required in index.js and vendor.js but with this plugin webpack will handle that and add js code only in vendor.js